# cordova no devices compatible in play store when export APK

Tags: android, cordova

I have testing aplication in emulator and i have export APK and instal in phone right.
But when i have sent this APK to Google play Alpha testing, say 0 devices compatibles, ¿Why? i can see like in my device is compatible.
I have used Phonegap 2.9.0
My manifest is this:

```
                <!-- all normal size screens -->
                <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>

                <!-- all large size screens with xxhdpi -->
                <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="large"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="large"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="large"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large"/>

                <!-- all large size screens with xxhdpi -->
                <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
                <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>

            </compatible-screens>
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        />
<!--     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    <application  android:icon="@drawable/copa_vino" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="false" >
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Carta" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your cordova/phonegap config.xml, have you specified min, max and target android sdk version ?

Exemple:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="21" />
```